# Передача данных в драйвер

Tags: windows, драйвер

Как отправить данные из юзер приложения в wdm драйвер?

Comment: Открыть файл устройства и записать в него данные, например...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Как я понимаю надо определить major function и потом в юзере вызывать WriteFile?

Comment: Как минимум, сначала CreateFile ;-) Я по кернелмоду не спец, почитайте Walter Oney, если я не путаю. Наши спецы его рекомендуют.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов хорошо, а в самом драйвере как это обрабатывать?

Comment: В обработчике IRP_MJ_WRITE. Именно его вызовут, когда кто-то в файл писать будет

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов И в WriteFile передавать дескриптор девайса?

Comment: Нет, handle, который вы получили до этого через CreateFile. Ну это в случае, если драйвер имеет свой файл устройства.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Но мне же не просто в файл писать надо, а как то это девайсу направить.

Comment: Драйвер должен "создать" специальный файл устройства, через который и может осуществляться взаимодействие с ним. Почитайте указанного автора, у него есть годная книга про все это.